# array double change value in list c#

Tags: c#, .net

I can't understand why the value of my list changes when I recalculated the variable     used to input the value in the list.

Look's an example.

```
List<double[]> myList = new List<double[]>();
double[] a = new double[3];

a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
myList.Add(a); // Ok List[1] = 1 2 3

a[0] = 4;      // List[1] = 4 2 3
a[1] = 5;      // List[1] = 4 5 3
a[2] = 6;      // List[1] = 4 5 6
myList.Add(a); // List[1] = 4 5 6 and List[2] = 4 5 6
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I strongly suggest to read [this](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx). Then you'll understand why that happens.

Comment: You add the **same instance** of `a` to the list twice....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `double[]` type is the reference type - [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c). So, when you add it into the List twice you actually add the same array twice.

`a[0]` before `myList.Add(a);` and after will change the same array - `List.Add` method does not create copy of the value you provide to it.

You should use new array each time or make a copy of it:

```
List<double[]> myList = new List<double[]>();
double[] a = new double[3];

a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
myList.Add(a); // Ok List[0] = 1 2 3

a = new double[3];
a[0] = 4;      // List[0] = 4 2 3
a[1] = 5;      // List[0] = 4 5 3
a[2] = 6;      // List[0] = 4 5 6
myList.Add(a); // List[0] = 1 2 3 and List[1] = 4 5 6
```